# trouble opening mysql from command line

Tags: mysql

windows 10 machine if that makes a difference. im following along from the book "php and mysql for dynamic websites" by Larry Ullman and im trying to access the mysql client. when i open cmd the following comes up

`c:users/psych>cd`

i presume thats normal, im just throwing it in because it isnt in the book.

so then according to the book i include the path to mysql through xampp

`c:\xampp\mysql\bin -u root -p;`

but it says

`c:\xampp\mysql\bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

can anyone help here?

Comment: `bin` is a folder name, you need to run the program within it: `c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql`

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention the path and the program name to run a program.

```
c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -u root -p
```

There are multiple programs in that `\bin\` folder.